# Access Forbidden in opening php files using Xampp on Mac

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this tutorial to lern php/mysql http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/simple-registration-system-php-mysql/

When i try to open the index.php which is saved in a folder in htdocs i get the access forbidden error

Access forbidden!

```
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Comment: Where did you install xampp? You'll want to make sure that htdocs or www, has its owner set to apache/apache2.

Comment: I installed xampp a week back.How do i set the owner to apache/apache2

Comment: Please take a look at, [permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13799). Make sure your document root has at least read permission. From this KB, you can also learn about how to change the owner of files and folders.

Comment: I did that but still get the same error